RainBird Controller Only Accessible on Same SSID, Not Across SSIDs (Same Subnet)
I'm having an issue with my RainBird controller, which is only accessible when my mobile device and the controller are on the same SSID. My mobile device is connected to SSID 1, and the RainBird is connected to SSID 4, both on the same AP and subnet. I can access other devices (e.g., TESTPC) across SSIDs, but the RainBird only works when both the mobile device and the RainBird are on the same SSID.
What I've checked:
AP Isolation: Disabled.
Firewall/ACLs: No restrictions; other devices are accessible.
Multicast/Broadcast: No filtering found.
Ping Test: I can ping the RainBird from SSID 1.
ARP Test: RainBird's IP appears in the ARP table even when connected to other SSIDs.


Are the SSIDs bridged together on your AP? (that is, are they really "same subnet" at ethernet level?) Does the ARP table show it together with MAC address or without?

All the wireless access points are connected to a switch which in turn is connected to a firewall which acts as the gateway.
As for the ARP i can see the controller's IP and MAC address.

All, as in more than one? You only said "the same AP" but how did you verify that? And the same question as before – are the two SSIDs actually on the same subnet as you say?  Do both SSIDs belong to the same bridge or VLAN? What are the IP configurations of each VLAN?

As i have previously explained there are multiple SSIDs broadcasted by an AP group. The APs have the same network configurations.
There are no VLANs as i explained the IP of the Controller is clearly visible from all SSIDs.

Being able to see the controller isn't what we're asking, as clearly your mobile device can't see it. We need to know the specific network configurations of each network in your environment. Are the different SSIDs running different networks/subnets? Is there a single DHCP server, or multiple?

-Single DHCP server.
-All the access points are connected to the same network and have the same subnet, all devices connected to any APs are able to connect with each other as i have previously explained except for the RAINBIRD controller and the mobile app.
